# Rails partial enumerating over associations extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, partial-views

I've got a Document model basically, which has_many Pages, and I have a view where I need to enumerate a bunch of documents (eg. 300) and make a button for each page. (I want to do pagination client side using the DataTables jQuery plugin so that the table can be sortable and searchable). The problem is that if I try to enumerate all the buttons for each Page in each Document, it takes over 10 seconds to render which is just not useful.

Is there any 'trick' to doing this kind of nested collection rendering fast? Should I just cache the fragments for each document (they don't change much once they're created)? Or is this just a bad situation for Rails partials and would my best bet be to do some client side rendering as part of the pagination in DataTables?

Edit: I'm already including associations so that I don't have an N+1 query problem, that's not the issue. And I tried caching, and it seems like that might be my solution for now because this index page gets reloaded often between every few documents being added, so it never has to rebuild the full cache of all the partials.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate need for caching seems like a code smell.  In lieu of guessing, have you tried profiling?  (e.g. http://hiltmon.com/blog/2012/02/27/quick-and-dirty-rails-performance-profiling/)

```
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Define a profiler:

```
# /lib/development_profiler.rb

class DevelopmentProfiler
  def self.prof(file_name)

    RubyProf.start
    yield
    results = RubyProf.stop

    # Print a flat profile to text
    File.open "#{Rails.root}/tmp/performance/#{file_name}-graph.html", 'w' do |file|
      RubyProf::GraphHtmlPrinter.new(results).print(file)
    end

    File.open "#{Rails.root}/tmp/performance/#{file_name}-flat.txt", 'w' do |file|
      # RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(results).print(file)
      RubyProf::FlatPrinterWithLineNumbers.new(results).print(file)
    end

    File.open "#{Rails.root}/tmp/performance/#{file_name}-stack.html", 'w' do |file|
      RubyProf::CallStackPrinter.new(results).print(file)
    end
  end
end
```

Wrap your view-logic with...

```
DevelopmentProfiler::prof("render-profiling") do
  # Your slow code here
end
```

---

**Edit - An additional thought**:  Because your model's data is not likely to change, it may be better to eat the rendering cost, once.  You could statically-generate the whole rendered page in an after_save callback.  Then just serve that single file for subsequent requests.

Though if charging a more traditional cache isn't a huge inconvenience, this may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: "The immediate need for caching seems like a code smell." I agree, unfortunately I have a million things to do on this project and limited time to do them in. I keep trying to push back and say that I need more time to do things properly, but meh... anyway, I tried profiling the view and it seems like 50% of the time is spent in Haml::Buffer#attributes called from Array#each which is essentially the major problem here - that I'm rendering two levels of nested objects which ends up being a lot of things.

Comment: I guess either I can try not rendering as many things by having the javascript cooperate with the server to do pagination, but I think fundamentally with nested associations things are always going to be somewhat slow, and caching this partial makes sense because once a Document has been processed, this partial will never change anyway.

Comment: I was kind of wondering if there was a "proper" way to iterate over a bunch of objects in a view, but there probably isn't anything better than Enumerable#each right?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an additional thought.  Though, are you rendering the partials with a single call for each element or a render on the nested collection? (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials  section on rendering collections)

Comment: There's a partial for a Document, which enumerates its Pages and draws an icon with some associated data for each page. The Documents are rendered as a collection though. I can't imagine that adding more abstraction by putting the Page icons in their own partial would help though.

Comment: Ah, as per your edit, I think the traditional cache achieves the same result with less complexity. I wish I could somehow "warm" the cache when the record is saved last so that I could achieve exactly the same result though. The one thing I didn't mention is that while the Pages are getting processed, the view does change (to reflect the number of pages that have been processed and their status). The cache is invalidated by having pages touch the parent Document when they are processed. So I guess for that reason the cache might be the simplest solution.